# Enable keyboard navigation of links in JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, jeditorpane

I want to enable keyboard navigation of HTML links in a Java Swing `JEditorPane`, is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, for non-editable panes, you need to bind keys to the `"previous-link-action"`, `"next-link-action"` and `"activate-link-action"` HTMLEditorKit actions in the InputMap. Here is a code sample:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;

public class Example {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws HeadlessException, InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> {
            final JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
            jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            jFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            final JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane();
            editor.setEditable(false);
            editor.setFocusable(true);
            editor.setContentType("text/html");

            final HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) editor.getDocument();
            final HTMLEditorKit editorKit = (HTMLEditorKit) editor.getEditorKit();

            try {
                doc.remove(0, doc.getLength());
                editorKit.insertHTML(doc, 0, "<a href=\"http://google.com\">link one</a> and <a href=\"http://bing.com\">link two</a>", 0, 0, null);
                editor.setCaretPosition(0);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            final InputMap inputMap = editor.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);

            final KeyStroke nextKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK);
            final KeyStroke prevKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_COMMA, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK);
            final KeyStroke goKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_G, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK);
            final Action prevAction = editor.getActionMap().get("previous-link-action");
            final Action nextAction = editor.getActionMap().get("next-link-action");
            final Action goAction = editor.getActionMap().get("activate-link-action");

            System.out.println("ks " + nextKey + " " + prevKey + " " + goKey);
            System.out.println("ac: " + nextAction + " " + prevAction + " " + goAction);

            inputMap.put(nextKey, "next-link-action");
            inputMap.put(prevKey, "previous-link-action");
            inputMap.put(goKey, "activate-link-action");

            editor.addHyperlinkListener(e -> {
                System.out.println(e.getURL());
            });

            jFrame.add(editor, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            jFrame.setSize(400, 400);
            jFrame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the link URL must be well formed (can be turned into a java URL) for the activate action to fire